# Stream photo/video to Android as camera on WSA

Tags: adb, camera, wsa

I am working with Windows Subsystem for Android (WSA) which does support ADB and should support any solution for Android.

The problem is I'm trying to set up Signal, but it needs to scan a QR code, and it does not detect my external webcam or OBS virtual webcam (verified by `adb shell dumpsys media.camera`).

I was hoping for a way to stream my screen/photo/video as a camera input.

Comment: Not exactly that, but I found a workaround for a similar issue: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/248254/how-to-use-the-camera-in-wsa-in-apps-that-dont-support-front-camera/248255#248255