# How to use the camera in WSA in apps that don't support front camera?

Tags: camera, front-camera, wsa

I've been trying to get an app to work on WSA (Windows Services for Android) but it needs a back camera, the only options I found Googling were either involving root (which is something I prefer to avoid in that case) or unsupported in the Android version (and probably won't work in that case wither).
What can I do to use the camera on such apps?

Answer (score 2):

I thought about that when I used an external USB camera, the Windows camera app treated it as a front camera and treated the built in one as a back facing camera, so I stopped WSA from the WSA settings, connected the external camera and started the app, sure thing, I could use my front camera in the app.
It treated it as a back camera.